# How to display single listview items in 2 columns and n number of rows in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list with 5 items (count 5 is dynamic). I need to display first item in first row column 1 and second item in first row column 2 and second item in second row column and so on. eg. in the attached image, consider all the items as a single list of names but displayed in multiple rows but with two columns. **Kindly don't suggest any plugin for this** In the attached image, list count is 12. Have to arrange 12 items as in the image.
[image: In the attached image list count is 12]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#vertical-grid

Comment: CollectionView supports this layout - see @MihailDuchev's link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**List view is not provide this functionality, You have to use collectionview instead of Listview**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout